# ORA-01722: invalid number when inserting decimal number in single quotes with

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting error ORA-01722: invalid number with following query:

```
insert into foo (id, some_number) values('id_01', '8.9');
```

What I've found so far:

1. I can run the query if I remove single quotes, like:

   insert into foo (id, some_number) values('id_01', 8.9);
2. Or if I change . to , like:

   insert into foo (id, some_number) values('id_01', '8,9');

I'm using Oracle database.

Funny thing: I'm located in Spain, where decimal numbers are written with , instead of .
Another developer in my team, not located in Spain can insert those values with the first query (with single quotes and .) which leads me to think this might be due to some system properties. My computer language is English, macOS Monterey 12.5.1

TABLE: FOO

```
Columns
NAME            DATA TYPE           NULL  DEFAULT    COMMENTS
*ID             VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   No
 SOME_NUMBER    NUMBER(3,1)         Yes
```

Comment: To avoid any culture-specific issues, use [*literals*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-192417E8-A79D-4A1D-9879-68272D925707) for constants. They have no any culture-dependent treatment and have fixed syntax. For example, numeric literal has a dot (`.`) as a decimal separator and it will be treated exactly the same in any client when you specify: `123.456 + .789`. And they are pure values of the type, there's no any (implicit) conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like issue with national language support, i.e. `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`.

```
SQL> create table foo (id varchar2(20), some_number number(3, 1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo(id, some_number) values ('id_01', '8.9');
insert into foo(id, some_number) values ('id_01', '8.9')
                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Failed (as you already know). If `nls_numeric_characters` is set to accept

- dot as a decimal character and
- comma as a group separator,

then it *works*:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into foo(id, some_number) values ('id_01', '8.9');

1 row created.

SQL>
```